# Webdriver C# -Click second linktext not first

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

By this line I click on the first text, but how can I click the second exact text?

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Play")).Click();
```

Comment: Hi, if that By.PartialLinkText("Play") retrieving multiple elements, then you can use FindElements right? to collect list of elements with same partial link text, by looping you can click on second link. off-course you can also try another locator may be xpath

Comment: Hi, I'm new in this, how Can I do this? "by looping you can click on second link." How to loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
  //get the list of elements which has same linkText
  List<IWebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Play"));

  //Click on each element by iterating the loop
  foreach (IWebElement element in all)
  {
       element.click();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but appears 5 errors to me, look the capture (I use webdriver C# in Visual Studio) http://i.imgur.com/0J8teoC.jpg

Comment: remove first two lines in your code. How many play buttons are there in your website??

Comment: Appear the same error also. NOTE: I see that the word <WebElement> in red until I add a letter "I" in: <IWebElement>, perhaps I need a different code for C#? Or what does it mean that for me only works IWebelement and not Webelement?

Comment: hi, the code provided above is in Java. you can do one thing, try by using xpath some thing like (//a[contains(text(),'Play')])[2]. it will select second play link text and click on it. (check the provided xpath is correct or not in firepath first).